# What are the names of kulas mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system

Mahabharata is the important Itihasa. Since it is itihasa related to Dvapara yuga, it contains Ramayana also.

Mahabharata may contain the names of many kulas like Suta. I am not asking about varna, jati, or any other classification, but only about kula.

What are the names of Kulas mentioned in Mahabharata?

**Note**: Kula here refers to the usage of the same word **कुल** in the actual Mahabharata. Synonyms are not needed. Whenever the original scripture uses the word कुल for something like सूत i.e., सूतकुल, then Suta is eligible as a kula. The word कुल may have any meaning in the context. It may refer to family, category, or any other thing. The word कुल is only the criteria. कुरुकुल, गुरुकुल, etc., are valid.

Comment: Thanks @SwiftPushkar. Edited. Please edit for improvement, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Airavata Kula is mentioned in Gita press version.

> **ऐरावतकुले** जातः सुमुखो नाम नागराट् । [Udyog Parva 103]